# Azure SWA How to Specify a PRODUCTION Build in GitHub Workflow .yml File?

Tags: angular, azure

Have a Static Web App (SWA) with integrated API, Azure has auto-gen a `.github/workflows/azure-static-web-apps-xxx.yml` file for `master` branch.

As I'm reading [Angular's Building and serving](https://angular.io/guide/build) that each environment should have its specific build like `ng build --configuration production` so this will take place

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ],
```

Although .yml has no `build` command, I found GitHub, Action tab, Build and Deploy Job log shows

```
...
56  Running 'npm install --unsafe-perm'...
...
86  > ui@0.0.0 build /github/workspace
87  > ng build
...
```

Without `--configuration production` line 87 will build a "development" by default and push to Azure.

Is there any way I can add a such configuration in .yml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.yml` builds PRODUCTION.

It's easy to check if your API have any reference to `process.env` as DEV stores them in `local.settings.json` but Azure Portal for PRODUCTION, or front-end's `environment.ts` vs. `environment.production.ts` in src\environments folder

Comment: Is it possible to specify that you want a development build as well as a production build?

Comment: @jjf130803 Usually we develop and build app locally, and you can make a staging branch/build at Github